# Looking for a work-around to AGOL's 30-minute cache

Tags: kml, arcgis-online, cache

Is there a way to bypass AGOL's 30-minute cache? We are serving up kmls through ArcGIS Online for power outages on an electric network and we need quicker updates than the set 30-minute time frame. Is this possible?

We've read that the KML utility service (http://utility.arcgis.com/sharing/kml) can be tweaked to ignore the cache, but we're not sure how to do this - any ideas?

I have looked for an answer here and posted a question to GeoNet as well, but have yet to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you may want to [alter the refresh rate](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/set-refresh-interval.htm).  I have done this to get real time feeds for police/fire/EMS as well as field resources for search & rescue.  All of these needed to have a much quicker refresh rate than the default.

This will refresh the data every x seconds/minutes. As long as the data that you are serving is being refreshed, your map should refresh with the updated data.

Comment: MaryBeth - thanks for the reply. Do you have the police/fire/EMS feeds in an ArcGIS Online web map? We have tested NOAA data that updates every 10 minutes, but it looks like the default 30-minute cache for AGOL is preventing the real-time updates from displaying. We altered the refresh rate in the web map and you can actually see the data flashing. Any ideas?

Comment: Update - we added kmls to our own web server, added these to AGOL maps, and set the refresh rate. We then made changes to the kmls and we're we able to see the changes in the web maps on-the-fly! Thanks again MaryBeth.